# Get fragment manager from a possible not already instantiated activty

Tags: java, android

I have an application where there are: a splash screen, a main activity (started from the splash screen) where there's a navigationView that attach and detach some fragment.
In one fragment i need to download some information with an AsyncTask. The problem is that the AsyncTask is called in the splash screen (the splash screen survive for 3 seconds) and the download can takes more or less than 3 seconds. In the `onPostExecute()` in AsyncTask i want to call a function `loadFeeback()` (that is in the fragment class) only if the fragment is already loaded, if not i set a static variable downloaded to true.

```
public void onPostExecute(Feedback[] feedbacks){
    Dati.feedbacks = feedbacks;

    if(mainActivity != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();

        FeedbackFragment feedbackFragment = ((FeedbackFragment) (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_feedback)));
        Dati.feedbackDownloaded = true;

        if (feedbackFragment != null)
            feedbackFragment.loadFeeback();
    }
}
```

The problem is that i can't get the mainActivity reference and i can't pass the context to the AsyncTask because it is called from the splash screen.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why do you not call the AsyncTask in the main activity ?

Comment: @Cochi I'd like to optimize the time

Answer (score 0):

The Asynctask is tied to the splash activity,because it created it.
Maybe you can use a Headless Fragment( fragment without layout):

Create a fragment on precise in the onCreate function :
`setRetainInstance(true)`

In your splash activity create the fragment and save him with a tag :

```
HeadlessFragment headlessFragment = new HeadlessFragment()

getSupportFragmentMangager().beginTransaction().add(headlessFragment, "fragmenttag").commit();
```

Launch your asynctask in the fragment

And when your main activy is launched retrieved the fragment :

```
HeadlessFragment headlessFragment = getSupportFragmentMangager().findFragmentByTag("fragmenttag");
```

So the fragment will be attached to the main activity, and you should call whatever you need

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: `So it will not survive the destroy of your activity.` Actually the Asynctask can outlive the activity and that can cause a memory leak if it is holding an activity reference.